# how create overlay EditText in Activity

Tags: android, overlay

like this:

[a link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMb2n.jpg)

please tell me .
Best able to provide demo.

Comment: Use a `Dialog` for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wel come to Stackoverflow.

Its not Dialog. its **Activity as a dialog**

[image]

```
public class diaActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test_dialog);
    }
}
```

test_dialog.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Cancle" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="OK" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPostalAddress" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

in android manifest file add your activity theme :

```
<activity
            android:name="diaActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog" >
        </activity>
```

for < 11 Api you have to use

```
<activity
            android:name="diaActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
        </activity>
```

Edited:

**close keyboard and exit use this code:**

```
public void onBackPressed() {

InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
      Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);

finish();

}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer,but i need keyboard Close together EditText.